# Service worker registration failed. Status code: 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm creating an extension for chrome, and i will need to use Firebase… but it's my first time with this tool and in kinda lost...

I'm using VS Code.

Furthermore, I have used the command `npm install firebase`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "****",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "***",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "webNavigation", "storage", "webRequest"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "native.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "logo_16.png",
      "48": "logo_48.png",
      "128": "logo_128.png",
      "256": "logo_256.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo_16.png",
    "48": "logo_48.png",
    "128": "logo_128.png",
    "256": "logo_256.png"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": ["myScript.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["Loader.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "firebase.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
}
```

and here is my service worker :

```
import { initializeApp } from "./node_modules/firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "./node_modules/firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "**********",
  authDomain: "******.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "*******",
  storageBucket: "********.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "**********",
  appId: "**********",
  measurementId: "**********",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Thanks !

I don't really know what could mess with it, so i don't really know where to start...

Comment: This firebase API probably isn't meant to be used inside a service worker. See if they have a special version, otherwise do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/), see also [examples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/).